# Clarification of HRESULT 0x80042710

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I'm using a COM library and a lot of times receive `HRESULT 0x80042710`. Looking at the [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd208031%28v=prot.10%29.aspx) site I can see that this exception means `At least one iSCSI session logout operation did not complete successfully.`.

What does this error mean and how do I fix it? There isn't much information on the web regarding this error.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look for err.exe from one of the Exchange resource kits. It works as a great general debugging tool. Download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=985) and see some basic use instructions [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexdan/archive/2008/02/28/looking-up-error-codes-with-err-exe.aspx). From the command line of your server it should provide you exactly the definition of what that error code means and where it is defined (via header file).

On my system the result is:

```
C:\Scripts>err 0x80042710
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), Facility: 0x4, Code 0x2710
# for hex 0x2710 / decimal 10000 :
  SQL_10000_severity_16                                         sql_err
# Unknown provider error.
# 1 matches found for "0x80042710"
```

If this is the same on your system it appears there is SQL error within your COM library.